# failing to `tar -zxvf` on a tarball with a symlink, inside Docker on Mac (tar: Cannot utime: No such file or directory)

Tags: docker, tar, alpine-linux

i am doing a build inside a docker container of Alpine Linux on Docker-On-Mac. inside the tarball there is a symlink to a local file (`README -> README.md`) that is failing the untaring:

```
tar: tarname.tar.gz/README: Cannot utime: No such file or directory
```

two interesting facts:

1. When running the same on Linux (Docker-on-Ubuntu running Alpine) it works flawlessly.
2. when running twice it succeeds, because README.md is already in the partially-created dir.

unfortunately on (2) above, it is untarring as park of a build program (Alpine's `abuild`) so i cannot just run the tar command twice.

any thoughts?

Comment: This may be a bug of Docker-On-Mac. There's a similar issue for `getcwd`: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1509, but it seem a slightly different scenario. Consider raising an issue for Docker-On-Mac.

Answer (score 0):

`tar` tries to get the 'file modified time', which fails for some files. As I don't know the contents of the archive, I cannot say why this happens.

But you can circumvent this problem by using the `-m` a.k.a. `--touch` flag, which let's tar ignore/not query the modification time:

```
tar -m -xzvf tarname.tar.gz
```